# Slingshot Energy into traveled distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy

If I have a slingshot and I am told that when pulled it has about $E$ joules of energy, how do I compute the height at which an object of mass $m$ would travel if the slingshot is released in the vertical direction?

I would imagine that the energy stored is potential energy, thus related to height $h$ through the following: $E = mgh$.

Is this correct or is there any other dissipating force strongly affecting the calculation?

I.e. If I have a slingshot with 1000 joules, and an object of mass 100 kilos will it travel $h = \frac{E}{m\times g} = \frac{1000}{100\times9.8} \approx 1$ meter vertically in the air?

Comment: Make sure you specify the point above which you measure: it has to be the height above the _fully extended_ catapult (because you do work against gravity as the rubber band contracts)

Comment: @ACuriosMind - This question is not homework related. I've seen a video on youtube about slingshots and got curios about the physics behind them.

Comment: @Floris - I would like it to be the height from the position of rest (so in this case it would be ground). Suppose the slingshot has already been contracted and the object is in place, what happens when you release?

Comment: If the sling shot has 1000J energy when extended, then it can lift the mass 1 m _from that point_. If the rubber was extended 0.2 m, the object will "fly" 0.8 m. This is further complicated by the question whether "equilibrium position" is the position of the object testing against (and extending) the sling. Is the energy stored at that point included in your 1000 J?

Comment: @Floris - Is see what you are saying. Lets suppose for simplicity that the slingshot has 1000 J when fully extended.

Comment: Slingshot relaxed = 0 J. With object supported, it has some energy stored ($\frac12 k x_0^2$). Fully stretched to $x_1$ it may have 1000 J stored. Is that $\frac12 k(x_1^2-x_0^2)$ or $\frac12 k x_1^2$? Because it is quite possible that the energy stored in the "object supported" state is already 1000 J... at which point you can't shoot the object at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your $E$ is potential energy in the rubber, which transforms to kinetic $K$.
So your starting velocity $v$ will be:

$E=1/2 mv^2$

From conservation of energy:

$0-1/2 mv^2=0-mgh$

$h=v^2/2g$ and $v^2=2E/m$

**Confirmed**

Interestingly enough the rubber does not obey Hook's law, and you need a lot more work if you want to find out what really happens.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Hookean_solid

Comment: So you are saying that my formula is correct?

Comment: I have the impression that your answer (and my question) is not considering the fact that the object is also facing the opposing force determined by gravity.

Comment: The force due to gravity **is** your potencial energy.$F=-dU/dx$